# Convert a dynamic JSON to a generic array in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following JSON produced by an application:

```
[{
    "market": "Thondwe",
    "commodity": 51,
    "price": "240",
    "date": "2016-07-07T00:00:00.000Z",
    "month": "07",
    "year": "2016",
    "dataSource": "Government",
    "priceType": 15,
    "unit": 5,
    "metadata": [{
        "Gender": "Male",
        "BirthYear": "1975"
    }]
}, {
    "market": "Thondwe",
    "commodity": 51,
    "price": "240",
    "date": "2016-07-07T00:00:00.000Z",
    "month": "07",
    "year": "2016",
    "dataSource": "Government",
    "priceType": 15,
    "unit": 5,
    "metadata": [{
        "Age": "67",
        "Sales": "1234",
        "City": "Somewhere"
    }]
}]
```

As you can see all the properties are always the same except for what is contained inside metadata, that contains an object that is always different and is built based on what the user has set.

I have to parse this JSON in C# and convert to an object.

Until today I've ignored the property **metadata**, and I've used the following code that works perfectly:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

public partial class JsonSchema
{
    [JsonProperty("templateId")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
    public int TemplateId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("frequency")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
    public int DataCollectionFrequencyID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("dataSource")]
    public string DataSource { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("dateFormat")]
    public string DateFormat { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("currency")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
    public int CurrencyID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("priceType")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
    public int PriceType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("rowHeader")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
    public int RowHeader { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("headerHash")]
    public string HeaderHash { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("discardedRows")]
    public List<string> DiscardedRows { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lastUpdateDate")]
    public DateTime LastUpdateDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("columns")]
    public List<Column> Columns { get; set; }
}

public partial class Column
{
    [JsonProperty("market")]
    public string Market { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("date")]
    public string Date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("commodity")]
    public string Commodity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("unit")]
    public string Unit { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("price")]
    public string Price { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("priceType")]
    public string PriceType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("dataSource")]
    public string DataSource { get; set; }
}

public partial class JsonSchema
{
    public static JsonSchema FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonSchema>(json, DataModel.Converter.Settings);
}

public static class Serialize
{
    public static string ToJson(this JsonSchema self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, DataModel.Converter.Settings);
}

internal static class Converter
{
    public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
        DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
        Converters =
        {
            new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
        },
    };
}

internal class ParseStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(int) || t == typeof(int?);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;
        var value = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
        int l;
        if (int.TryParse(value, out l))
        {
            return l;
        }
        throw new Exception("Cannot unmarshal type long");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (untypedValue == null)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, null);
            return;
        }
        var value = (int)untypedValue;
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value.ToString());
        return;
    }

    public static readonly ParseStringConverter Singleton = new ParseStringConverter();
}
```

The problem now is that I need to retrieve also the object stored in the metadata property, but how can I map it?

Consider that all the values of the properties inside metadata are always string

Comment: Make a new property which is an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`? (If someone has a better option than dynamic, please use that instead)

Comment: You should be able to map metadata to `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`.

Comment: Or Dictionary<string, string>[] works, too. It's a bit odd, and I'm sure there are better ways of doing this. Here's more options according to newtonsoft http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingCollections.htm

Comment: @Will Thanks!! that's exactly what I need! if you write the answer I accept it and we will help someone else.